# Run react native 0.51 on newer devices

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

I have a react-native project run on 0.51. How to upgrade gradle build to run on newer android devices (API 31-33) without upgrade react-native version? Is this posible?

I try edit build.gradle both app and android (which run perfect in react-native 0.59), but 0.51, alway error when bundle

[image]